# Text Field Getting misaligned after selecting text field with auto complete in Oracle Apex

Tags: javascript, css, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdH9Q.png)

The first image is when type selected as a text field

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWBaA.png)

The second image is when the type is selected as a text field with autocomplete

The CSS properties in the second image (height, width, and border) is altered on selecting autocomplete. I tried changing by adding styles in Custom Attributes, but it didn't work.

`style= "width:300px; height:min-content; border:black;"`

Comment: Pardon me, but these two images look exactly the same (apart from the fact that one is text field, another text field with autocomplete). There's no evidence that *alignment* is changed. Or, I don't see it.

Comment: @Littlefoot Can you check the images once more, it would be much more clear now? In the second image, the CSS properties of the text field are changed (the height, width, and border). I tried changing the CSS properties manually using custom attributes, but didn't work

Comment: OK, now I understand; it is not "alignment" (the way I understood it) but height/width/border. Unfortunately, I wouldn't know how to fix it, nor why text field with autocomplete differs from an "ordinary" text field. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist.